# parsing xml via SAXParser contain html tag

Tags: android

I have parse data from xml that contain html tag.
i am not able to get image src attribute can any one show this link.
http://mobileecommerce.site247365.com/admin/catdata.xml
i give you url it's not mean that i want to show whole code from you.i mean give some links or some idea for that.

Thanks in advance

Arpit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String str = "Your Cat_Desc tag value";
    String[] temp;

        if (str.contains("<img src=")) {
                                temp = str.split("<img src=");
                                String imagesUrl = temp[1].substring(
                                temp[1].indexOf("\""), temp[1]
                                                .indexOf(" "));
                                imagesUrl = imagesUrl
                                    .replace("\"", " ");
                                System.out.println("My image URL :: " +imagesUrl);
                                }else    {
                              System.out.println("NO imageurl found");           }
```

Comment: thanks for reply divyesh.i will implement it then i catch you.

Comment: i checked using your url and your Cat_Desc tag value.........its work fine for me...............