# How to split a string and get a specific string in android?

Tags: android

I want to split a string and get a word finally. My data in database is as follows.

> Mohandas Karamchand Gandhi (1869-1948), also known as Mahatma Gandhi, was born in Porbandar in the present day state of Gujarat in India on October 2, 1869. 
>   He was raised in a very conservative family that had affiliations with the ruling family of Kathiawad. He was educated in law at University College, London.
>   src="/Leaders/gandhi.png"

From the above paragraph I want get the image name "gandhi". I am getting the index of "src=". But now how can I get the image name i.e "gandhi" finally.

My Code:

```
int index1;
public static String htmldata = "src=";
if(paragraph.contains("src="))
{
   index1 = paragraph.indexOf(htmldata);
   System.out.println("index1 val"+index1);
}
else
   System.out.println("not found");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7755958/776244

Comment: hi thanks for reply...but how can I get the image name from that?

Comment: see my answer. Pass the string to it. The return value is the image name before `.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. Check if it working for you..

```
public String getString(String input)
    {
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("src=.*/(.*)\\..*");
        Matcher mt = pt.matcher(input);
        if(mt.find())
        {
            return mt.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Update:**
Change for multiple item -

```
public ArrayList<String> getString(String input)
    {
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("src=.*/(.*)\\..*");
        Matcher mt = pt.matcher(input);
        while(mt.find())
        {
            ret.add(mt.group(1));
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Now you'll get an arraylist with all the name. If there is no name then you'll get an empty arraylist (size 0). Always make a check for size.

Comment: Hi thank you...its working fine...I am able to get the name of the image....but in my database for some rows there are two images..then how can I get the two image names? Please suggest me...

Comment: If the formate is same, use `while` instead of `if`. `while(mt.find())`. But don't return- instead save them to array of `String` then return array.

Comment: hi i kept like this static ArrayList<String> imgs;
  while(mt.find())
        {
         System.out.println("my.group(1)"+mt.group(1));
         imgs.add(mt.group(1));
         return imgs;
        } but it is returning null

Comment: hi thanks a lot..if i want to get the image name with extension how can i do that?

Comment: Use this regex instead.. `"src=.*/(.*\\.[^\\\"]*)"` This is escaped string. So just replace just like this. `Pattern.compile("src=.*/(.*\\.[^\\\"]*)");`

Comment: Hi I have changed my image path in db i.e src="imagename.png". So now I want to get the image name with extension. Please help me